# Delphi Generic List to string

Tags: delphi, generics

I am looking at a generic list which can be written to an Array of string for any object based on a particular field. The base List will have a number of descendants. The Code for the declaration is shown below and compiles fine:

```
unit TestList;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.Rtti, System.Generics.Collections, system.SysUtils;

type
  TMakeString<T> = reference to function(const input: T): String;

  TMyList<T>=class(TList<T>)
  protected
    function GenericAsString(const Value): string;
    Function CastToString(const Value: T): string; virtual;
  public
    Function MakeArray:TArray<string>;
  end;

  TMyObject=class(TObject)
  private
    fname: string;
  public
    property Name:string read fname write FName;
  end;

  TMyObjectList<T:TMyObject>=class(TMyList<T>)
  protected
    Function CastToString(const Value: T): string; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyList<T> }

function TMyList<T>.CastToString(const Value: T): string;
begin
  result:='';
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(string) then
    Result := GenericAsString(Value);
end;

function TMyList<T>.GenericAsString(const Value): string;
begin
  Result := String(Value);
end;

function TMyList<T>.MakeArray: TArray<string>;
var
  i:integer;
begin
  setlength(Result,0);
  for i := 0 to count-1 do
    Result[i]:=CastToString(Items[i]);
end;

{ TMyObjectList<T> }

function TMyObjectList<T>.CastToString(const Value: T): string;
begin
  result:=TMyObject(T).Name;
end;

end.
```

When I implement this code using the following:

```
var
  MyList:TMyList<string>;
  AList1:Tarray<string>;

begin
  MyList:=TMyList<string>.create;
  MyList.Add('Name1');
  MyList.Add('Name1');
  Alist1:=MyList.MakeArray;
end;
```

I keep getting an AV during the MakeArray call when it calls the CastToString function and tries to return a result. The same happens when I invoke the TMYObjectList at the same point.

I am not sure if my use of generics here is effective or appropriate to this situation, and if not is there a better way to do this? I was toying with using an anonymous method approach as well but wasn't sure how to go about this.

Comment: If you are using D2009+ then all `TObject`s have a virtual `.ToString` method.  Override and implement this in your classes and your job becomes much easier.

Comment: ...actually, you're using generics, so you must be using D2009+

Comment: @J... yep, if he can se `ToString` then he can experiment like this: http://pastebin.com/BmqDkeBw

That being said, you can not externally implement Visitor for classes that you take for granted from another source (like VCL classes). Whatever `.ToString` they have out of the box - would be most probably the only thing you can use.

Outside-of-class `TMakeString<T>` breaks this dependency even if looking less laconic and elegant.

Comment: I remember now seeing that in the source and agree it is a useful approach, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: On another note your example of class helper won't compile! (XE8). All other examples show this approach on non generic types. There have been other posts on this back to D2009 which suggested this was not possible, only for instantiated types which kind of defeats the purpose. Best approach might be the inherited method way.

Answer (score 8):

Your first problem lies here:

```
function TMyList<T>.MakeArray: TArray<string>;
var
  i:integer;
begin
  setlength(Result,0); // <--- oops
  for i := 0 to count-1 do
    Result[i]:=CastToString(Items[i]);
end;
```

That should be

```
SetLength(Result, Count);
```

Then consider this function:

```
function TMyList<T>.GenericAsString(const Value): string;
begin
  Result := String(Value);
end;
```

You cannot just cast an arbitrary variable to a string and hope that it will work. It so happens that in your code you only call this function when `Value` is a string, but that's not a good approach. You might be better removing `GenericAsString` and writing `CastToString` as:

```
function TMyList<T>.CastToString(const Value: T): string;
begin
  Result := TValue.From<T>(Value).ToString;
end;
```

However, even that has dubious utility in my view.

This code is also wrong:

```
function TMyObjectList<T>.CastToString(const Value: T): string;
begin
  result := TMyObject(T).Name;
end;
```

Remember that `T` is a type. You are casting a type to an instance. That always fails.

You would write this like so:

```
function TMyObjectList<T>.CastToString(const Value: T): string;
begin
  result := Value.Name;
end;
```

It's very hard to advise you on how to proceed. I don't think that it makes sense for the list class to implement the capability of obtaining a string representation of one of its members. But exactly where and how that functionality should be implemented very much depends on your overall requirements. Which we simply cannot see.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious errors. I have found myself using this feature more than once, mostly in diagnostics and therefore thought to include it in the base class.